# How to limit the number of MYSQL Database connections?

Tags: java, mysql

I am developing an application in Java which will be distributed across many people. However I don't want a thousand clients connected at the same time therefore I want to limit the number of connections on my Apache MYSQL Server. I am using xampp for this and I wanna know how do I limit/change the number of connections at one time.

Comment: Note that you **should not** allow external clients to connect to your MySQL database. [That way lies disaster.](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?noseen=0&threadid=2803713&pagenumber=258#post398884189)

Comment: @duskwuff Users won't be able to modify my database. The application is going to do it by itself updating things like location, ip, user desktop name etc Users wont be able to execute commands on my mysql server

Comment: Okay, good! Just making sure, since it wasn't clear from your question what your architecture would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really broad, so my answer has to be broad as well.

You should study more how connections and clients work.

Just because you have thousands of clients, it doesn't mean you will need thousands of connections. This is because every client doesn't take up one connection.

What happens is, at some level, a pool of connections is created and this pool of connections is shared amongst all client calls.

The last "p" in your `xampp` means `PHP` (or `Perl`), so they would be the ones responsible for controlling the connection pool. So, my advice is look for connection pools in `PHP` or `Perl`.

As an example on how to use connection pool with Java, follow this tutorial: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076221/jndi/dive-into-connection-pooling-with-j2ee.html

Comment: The client will need to enter records and read records from MYSQL Database. That will obviously require it to be connected. I want it to be queued e.g 200 connected, once they enter record, another client enters the queue. But I do not know the concept of "pool of connections". I will read on about that. But for now all I need to know is how to limit my connections because whenever I connect like a few clients, it prints out "max number of connections reached" so I'm sure there is a config file for that.

Comment: You limit the number of connections through the pool. If there are only X connections in the pool, then a maximum of X connections will be open and in use.

Comment: Hmm...can you give me some reference or link to read more about connection pools and how to implement them in Java?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, I'd recommend c3p0

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

or  Apache Commons DBCP

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

http://wiki.apache.org/commons/DBCP

Cheers!